# Return elements of JSON array column on separate rows in Redshift

Tags: python, postgresql, amazon-redshift, user-defined-functions

I have a Redshift table that has a JSON array in one column:

```
 id | metadata
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 1  | [{"pet":"dog","country":"uk"}, {"pet":"cat","country":"us"}]
 2  | [{"pet":"cat","country":"uk"}]
 3  | []
```

I want a table that looks like this:

```
 id |   pet   |  country
------------------------
 1  | dog       | uk
 1  | cat       | us
 2  | cat       | uk
```

Is there a way to do this using sql commands and or python user-defined functions on a Redshift table

Answer (score 0):

I use this (ugly) method for Redshift. Let `seq` be a table with single field `num` containing numbers from 1 to 10000 (assume that you haven't more than 10000 pets in one row). You can use `generate_series(1, 10000)`, but for strange reasons it slower :(

```sql
select
  id,
  JSON_EXTRACT_PATH_TEXT(single_metadata, 'pet') as pet,
  JSON_EXTRACT_PATH_TEXT(single_metadata, 'country') as country
from
(
  select
    t.id,
    cast(JSON_EXTRACT_ARRAY_ELEMENT_TEXT(t.metadata, num) as json) as single_metadata
  from 
    t join seq -- or (select num from generate_series(1, 10000))
  on num <= json_array_length(t.metadata)
)
```

Comment: I had tried this, but I didn't want to hard-code the number, like here to 10000

Comment: You can get this number via query like `select max(json_array_length(t.metadata)) from t`

Comment: So I had a table seq `CREATE TEMP TABLE seq
(i int); INSERT INTO seq VALUES(0),(1),(2);` but how do I use `select max(json_array_length(t.metadata))` as a insert-select combo command to insert data in seq?

Comment: Only via python script :(